# is there a way to save the volume setting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When I play music, and I set the volume to 20% for example, when the bot leaves the voice channel, and then I play another music, the volume goes back to 100%, and I have to set it again manually to 20% again.
I want to make my bot save the volume I set. Is there any way to do that?
my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"),
client = new Discord.Client,
const { Player } = require("discord-player");
const player = new Player(client, { quality: 'highestaudio', enableLive: true, leaveOnEmpty: false, leaveOnEnd: false, leaveOnStop: false, autoSelfDeaf: false, });
client.player = player;

client.on("message", async (message) => {

    const args = message.content.slice(settings.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === "volume"){
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`  You're not in a voice channel !`);

        if (message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) return message.channel.send(`You are not in the same voice channel !`);

        if (!client.player.getQueue(message)) return message.channel.send(` No music currently playing !`);

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`The current volume is: **${client.player.getQueue(message).volume}**`);
        
        if (Math.round(parseInt(args[0])) < 1 || Math.round(parseInt(args[0])) > 100) return message.channel.send(` Please enter a valid number (between 1 and 100) !`);
           
          client.player.setVolume(message, parseInt(args[0]));
          message.channel.send(`Volume set to **${parseInt(args[0])}%** !`);
    }

});
```

Comment: You're going to have to store the setting somewhere, preferably a database. Alternatively you could hoist a property to your client object, however that too will be reset once the bot shuts off

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: `client.something = someValue;` as example for hoisting to the client, for a database it's best for you do some external research

Comment: Just an example of what you can do with Elitezen's previous comment: `client.vol = parseInt(args[0])`, and then you can access the volume with `client.vol`!

Answer (score 0):

Hoisting to the client would be a quicker solution but it would lose its value when you restart the bot.

If you want it to retain its value after bot restarts, you can use the filesystem module and store the value in a JSON file or a text file if you so wish.

A more simple method would be to hoist the value to the client, e.g. `client.volume = 20;`

You would then be able to retrieve the value by using `client.volume`.

Hope this helped.